# hide header while collection view is loading

Tags: swift, header, collectionview

I am using `NVActivityIndicatorView` for loading animation.
I have these function to add and remove activity indicator.

```
func addActivityIndicator() {}
func startActivityIndicatorView() {}
func stopActivityIndicatorView() {}
```

I have a header which I implement in

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
   let headerView = ...
   return headerView 
}
```

My problem is header is visible while collectionView is loading. I want to hide it while `collectionView` is loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably performing some asynchronous operation while the indicator is animating so you should let the collection view know that the operation is finished by calling `reloadData` so it'll re-layout its UI elements including the headers via `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`:

First off, what you need is to return `CGSize.zero` from [`collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617702-collectionview) if indicator is on screen so the header won't be populated:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
  if indicatorView.isAnimating { 
    return CGSize.zero
  } else {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 50)
  }
}
```

Then wherever you hide the activity indicator *(probably in the completion block of the asynchronous operation)*, you should call `collectionView.reloadData` so `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` will be called again:

```
// operation is done, refreshing the content..
self.stopActivityIndicatorView()
self.collectionView.reloadData() 
...
```

Comment: viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind is not accepting return of nil.

Comment: Oh sorry, I totally missed that but nevermind. If indicator is animating, you need to return `CGSize.zero` for header height in the respective delegate method instead. Leave `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` as is and just update [`referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617702-collectionview?language=objc) using same idea.