# UICollectionView Top spacing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, spacing

i have a Problem with my UICollectionView inside my Swift Xcode Project
[image]
I checked all insets and margins, I tried the ViewController's: "Adjust Scroll View Insets" and lots of other stuff, but none of them did change this in any way.

i want to reduce / remove that top spacing above the first row of cells in my collectionView

I created a sample project to find a solution/fix for this issue, but didn't had any luck yet

This seems to be a issue when using a Collection View inserted via Storyboard /Interface builder, because this does not happen if I add the collectionView on the code side

Here's my View Controller's Code:

```
import UIKit

struct CVData: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var value: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, CVData>!
    var cvDataList: [CVData] = []
    enum Section {
        case main
    }
    var CVDataLabels: [String] = ["Label1:","Label2:","Label3:","Label4:","Label5:","Label6:","Label7:","Label8:"]
    var CVDataValues: [String] = []
    var snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, CVData>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureCollectionView()
        buildData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func configureCollectionView() {
        
        let layoutConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
        let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: layoutConfig)
        myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = listLayout
        myCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, CVData> { (cell, indexPath, item) in

            var content = UIListContentConfiguration.cell()
            content.text = item.name
            content.textProperties.font.withSize(8.0)
            content.textProperties.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
            content.secondaryText = item.value
            content.prefersSideBySideTextAndSecondaryText = true
            content.textProperties.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, CVData>(collectionView: myCollectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: CVData) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            
            // Dequeue reusable cell using cell registration (Reuse identifier no longer needed)
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration,
                                                                    for: indexPath,
                                                                    item: identifier)
            // Configure cell appearance
            cell.accessories = [.disclosureIndicator()]
            
            return cell
        
    }
    }


    func buildData() {
        
        let cvDataList = [
            CVData(name: self.CVDataLabels[0], value: "value1"),
            CVData(name: self.CVDataLabels[1], value: "value2"),
            CVData(name: self.CVDataLabels[2], value: "value3"),
            CVData(name: self.CVDataLabels[3], value: "value4"),
            CVData(name: self.CVDataLabels[4], value: "value5"),
            CVData(name: self.CVDataLabels[5], value: "value6"),
            CVData(name: self.CVDataLabels[6], value: "value6"), //added 20210510
            CVData(name: self.CVDataLabels[7], value: "value7")
        ]
        
        // Create a snapshot that define the current state of data source's data
        self.snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, CVData>()
        self.snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        self.snapshot.appendItems(cvDataList, toSection: .main)

        // Display data in the collection view by applying the snapshot to data source
        self.dataSource.apply(self.snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}
```

Here's the Size inspector settings from that UICOllectionView
[image]

Any help'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens if you reduce CollectionView height (or increase height of each cell) ? Could it be a headerView, with no content ?        Maybe you could try to force to zero size ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139749/hide-header-while-collection-view-is-loading

Comment: send us screenshot of size inspector... i doubt you have header size there

Comment: Thanks for your time claude31 and Fahim Parkar, as I understood these settings, I don't want a header size in here, so the header Size is set zu zero (see added screenshot above)

Comment: if I reduce the height of the collection View, the last row with cells get cut, but the top part does not change at all :/ as you can see this is just a sample project with nothing else in it than this collectionView...if I reduce the width the rows get smaller and the spacing on both sides stay also the same..just like padding behaves in f.e. javascript/php/html...but I just can't find those padding settings anywhere in Xcode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't worked with `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list`, so this is just from some quick research and experimentation...

The default `.headerMode` for `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` is `.none` ... when using `.insetGrouped` that results in the "extra space" we're seeing.

Curiously, there is also a `headerTopPadding` property, which we might expect to be of help here. It's default is `0` ... but that appears to only be applied if there ***IS*** a header view.

So, if we set `.headerMode = .supplementary` and return an empty `UICollectionReusableView` for the header, we can get rid of the extra space:

[image]

Now, the top space is the same as the default left/right padding.

Here's what I used for the header view:

```
class EmptyHeaderView : UICollectionReusableView {
    static let reuseIdentifier:String = "emptyHeaderView"
}
```

and three edits to your `configureCollectionView()` func:

```
func configureCollectionView() {
    
    var layoutConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
    
    // 1
    // we're going to supply an "empty" header supplementary view
    layoutConfig.headerMode = .supplementary
    
    let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: layoutConfig)
    
    myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = listLayout
    myCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, CVData> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
        
        var content = UIListContentConfiguration.cell()
        content.text = item.name
        content.textProperties.font.withSize(8.0)
        content.textProperties.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        content.secondaryText = item.value
        content.prefersSideBySideTextAndSecondaryText = true
        content.textProperties.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
        cell.contentConfiguration = content
    }
    
    dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, CVData>(collectionView: myCollectionView) {
        (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: CVData) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
        
        // Dequeue reusable cell using cell registration (Reuse identifier no longer needed)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration,
                                                                for: indexPath,
                                                                item: identifier)
        // Configure cell appearance
        cell.accessories = [.disclosureIndicator()]
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    // 2
    // register a reusable supplementary view for the header
    myCollectionView.register(EmptyHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: EmptyHeaderView.reuseIdentifier)

    // 3
    // provider for header suppleentary view
    dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = { (collectionView: UICollectionView, kind: String, indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView? in
        if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
            if let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: EmptyHeaderView.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? EmptyHeaderView {
                return headerView
            }
        }
        fatalError("Something's wrong with the setup...")
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, finally it all makes sense - great explanation and also great solution with the empty header section!  I should have tried to switch to .plain instead of .insetGrouped, maybe I'd found the solution this way by myself. I already spent some hours finding the cause for this, I can't tell how thankful I am, DonMag! very much appreciated! thank you!

Comment: @blendstylez - glad it helped... quite often, I get tunnel-vision on a problem, and all it takes is a "fresh set of eyes." :)

Comment: I know absolutely what you mean @DonMag, nevertheless I should've seen or tried this, but I was searching in the IB instead, bc I thought if it works added via code it has to be something with IB :/ because I do this all by myself there's no one else who could help me get a different angle...at least - lesson learned :) thanks! 

Comment: Same problem and solution for the `.grouped` appearance. Thanks!